# Zend Navigation (breadcrumbs) not displaying

Tags: php, zend-framework, breadcrumbs, zend-navigation

I'm having a problem displaying breadcrumbs with Zend_Navigation.

I have a single controller that takes in a parameter to query out articles from the DB. So, if you point to "articles/view/id/3", it returns the article with an id of 3. The problem I'm having is having breadcrumbs work under this logic. Ideally, when going to "articles/view/id/3" I'd like the breadcrumbs to be: "Articles > Article_Name"

My code renders the navigation and sub navigation alright, it just fails on the breadcrumbs, currently not displaying anything.

Here's my code:

1) Site's navigation in an XML format that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<zend-config xmlns:zf="http://framework.zend.com/xml/zend-config-xml/1.0/">
  <nav>
    <articles>
      <label>Articles</label>
      <uri>/</uri>
      <order>1</order>
      <active>1</active>
      <visible>1</visible>
      <pages>
        <article_one>
          <label>Article One</label>
          <uri>/articles/view/id/81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c</uri>
          <order>1</order>
          <active>1</active>
          <visible>1</visible>
        </article_one>
      </pages>
    </articles>
  </nav>
</zend-config>
```

2) Navigation (In the layout):

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'nav');
$nav = new Zend_Navigation($config);
$view = new Zend_View();
$view->navigation($nav);
echo $view->navigation()->menu();
```

3) Breadcrumbs (in the Articles controller):

```
public function init() {
        $uri = $this->_request->getPathInfo();
        $activeNav = $this->view->navigation()->findByUri($uri);
        $activeNav->class = "selected";
        $activeNav->active = true;
    }
```

4) Breadcrumbs (In the layout):

```
//Doesn't display anything[/B]
echo $view->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setLinkLast(true);
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Not sure breadcrumps work with uri. I think you need to specify controller and action tags for your navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what parameters URI for?
Where are parameters `controller` & `action`?

Your can look here http://framework.zend.com/manual/ru/zend.view.helpers.html
Or source code `Zend/View/Helper/Navigation/Breadcrumbs.php`

Comment: Thank you! I needed to specify the controller, action and params in the navigation.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Just to point this out, Actualli breadcrumbs work with uri.

The problem is that `$this->view->navigation()->findByUri($uri)` returns a null object;
because even though it is setup in the bootstrap its not seen.

Adding `Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Navigation', $navigation);` in your bootstrap file should solve the problem.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `/` to the URL. I had the same problem too.